# xpath - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, expression

how can I use Xpath to retrieve the port number (4145) contained in the following code ? :

```
<tr>
<td data-label="IP:port ">
 <span class="labelText">IP:port </span>
 <span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="proxyIp[]" value="202.57.33.134|r4883">
 </span>
 202.57.33.134:
 <span class="r4883">4145</span>
</td>
[more <td></td> ... ]
</tr>
```

my last attempt is making an error :

> print(i.xpath('.//td[1]/span[3]/text()')[0])
> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml in your question is invalid; the `<input>` node is not properly closed. If you close that (the way @hintze did in his answer), you can use, in addition to his proposal, use this xpath expression as well:

```
//tr/td//span[@class="r4883"]
```

Comment: thanks for your help, Yeah this <input> node is weird ... it's not from me, it's a copy-past from the website : https://premproxy.com/socks-list/ (i try to scrap proxies adrss). Sadly your solution didn't work either because the class name is not static .... it was one of my first attempt .

Comment: @Xodarap Interesting; I took a look at that page and indeed the span class is dynamic; that actually is not a real problem and the xpath expression can be modified to address that - the real problem is that in the page sources for a couple of those pages, those spans have empty values, so I couldn't find the equivalent to your `4145` target. They all look like this: `<span class="whatever"></span>`.

Comment: Yeah that's very annoying ... A solution would be to ask XPath to find all <span> that have a class name composed of 5 characters. I mean the probability of finding an off-topic <span>  is pretty small but I don't know how to ask Xpath to do that.

Comment: @Xodarap After checking some more, the bottom line is those pages use invalid xml. I would suggest you load the page to an html parser like lxml, which is pretty tolerant of invalid code and try xpath from there. It may or may not work for all entries, though.

Comment: Ok I will try that or find another website. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I had to change your example XML a little bit, stored into `test.xml` in the following example:

```
<tr>
<td data-label="IP:port ">
 <span class="labelText">IP:port </span>
 <span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="proxyIp[]" value="202.57.33.134|r4883"></input>
 </span>
 <span class="r4883">4145</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Then, the value `4145` is printed on the terminal when executing this script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

root = et.parse("test.xml")

print(root.findall(".//td[1]/span[3]")[0].text)
```

As you can see, `text` is an attribute of the element found at the XPath `/td[1]/span[3]`.

Comment: I really thought that was the solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work on my side... the problem remains the same... Why did you change the HTML? Did the deleted line prevent the script from working?

Comment: well, I did not understand it being HTML, but rather XML (we were talking XPath and the question is labelled XML). The deleted line was not enclosed in an XML tag. Hence, the XML was invalid.

Could you say why it doesn't work on your side? I tested this with Python 3.6.3.